# Запрос данных 4-х таблиц

Tags: php, sql

Задача сделать запрос который получает данные из таблицы, которая не связана напрямую с таблицей условия. В общем до сих пор слишком сложно, попробую нарисовать.

4 таблицы:

```
+cases-------------+client-----------+punishment---------+default_values+
|case_name         |client_id(связан)|punishment_id      |max_case_value|
|client_id(связан>)|                 |client_id (<связан)|min_case_value|
|case_value        |                 |punishment_value   |              |
```

В конце концов эти данные мне нужно будет отобразить вот так: 
Вывести название дела и расчет максимальное значение(оно всегда одинаковое) - case_value(свое для каждого дела) - punishment_value(свое для каждого клиента)

```
case_name1 max_case_value - case_value1 - punishment_value
```

Отнимать буду в PHP, но я запутался настолько что не понимаю как получить эти данные в свои переменные для удобного циклического прохода по ним.

Если непонятно - задайте вопрос, я отлично понимаю что я обьясняю очень плохо, но не знаю как описать лучше.

Comment: Какое отношение между `case и client` и `client и punishment`?

Comment: client - case (1 - n); client - punishment (1 - n);

Comment: Получается, что отношение между `case` и `punisment` - Многое-Ко-Многим, реализуемое через `client`, правильно я понимаю?

Comment: @MichaelPak похоже на то

Comment: Тогда получается для одного `case` надо из его `case_value` вычесть все `punishment_value`, с которым у него одинаковый `client`, да?

Comment: @MichaelPak верно, но при этом полученное число так же вычитается из max_case_value, что в итоге строит ответ.

Comment: Добавьте данную информацию в Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Сделали бы уже [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) с структурой базы и примером данных.

Comment: @MichaelPak по идее это она: max_case_value - case_value1 - punishment_value по крайней мере я так задумывал. Не подумал, сейчас сделаю fiddle.

Comment: @Levelleor Я посмотрел структуру вашей базы из прошлых вопросов. Мне кажется проблема в структуре базы. Мне почему то кажется, что punishment должно быть напрямую связано с case. Потому как наказания даются на основании какого то дела. И у меня ощущение что клиентов в одном деле может быть более одного, а тогда вопрос что за value которое в деле.

Comment: @MichaelPak value в деле это оценка адвоката которая говорит на сколько высокий шанс выиграть дело. punishment отдельно ибо наказания даются не только этой конторой и ее делами, а именно общая база, которая имеет много записей на эту тему. Я полагаю если клиента 2 то в ячейку с именем можно написать это, если нет то можно написать в описание. Я создал пример фидла, то что вы нашли в прошлых постах немножко изменилось дотеперь. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9130c

Comment: в общем с punishment все должно быть просто, типа sum(punishment_value), но это пока только одна цифра

Comment: @MichaelPak Не придумали ли вы ничего интересного на мою тему? Потому что я, кажись, только глубже в лес захожу, пытаясь придумать запрос. Как думаете, будет ли правильным вытащить эти данные 3-4-мя запросами?

Comment: Зависит от нагрузки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например как нибудь так:

```
SELECT CL.client_full_name,C.client_id,C.case_name,C.case_value,
       (SELECT IFNULL(sum(punishment_value),0)
          FROM punishment P
         WHERE P.client_id=C.client_id) punishment_val,
       D.max_case_value
  FROM cases C, default_values D, client CL
 WHERE CL.client_id=C.client_id
```

Так как `default_values` не связана с остальными таблицами никакими условиями в ней обязана быть *одна и только одна* запись. Либо, если записей там несколько надо условиями отбора добиться что бы выбиралась требуемая. В случае если вопреки всем ожиданиям в ней окажется более 1 записи то результирующих строк под одному делу окажется несколько.

Я намеренно не использовал JOIN т.к. в простых случаях в большинстве СУБД они не требуются, в них появляется необходимость только в случае LEFT JOIN

Вариант 2 (с LEFT JOIN):

```
SELECT CL.client_full_name,C.client_id,C.case_name,C.case_value,
       D.max_case_value,
       IFNULL(sum(punishment_value),0) punishment_val
  FROM default_values D,client CL,
       cases C
  LEFT JOIN punishment P ON P.client_id=C.client_id
 WHERE CL.client_id=C.client_id
 GROUP BY CL.client_full_name,C.client_id,C.case_name,C.case_value
```

Оба варианта в принципе равнозначны. Я привел их что бы показать степени свободы при написании запросов.

Comment: Ох.. Все довольно просто. Если вас не затруднит, не скажете в чем же реально идея LEFT JOIN, почему его нужно использовать в запросах к связанным таблицам и что оно такое? Я уже долго ищу открытый ответ на сей вопрос..

Comment: @Levelleor Вы возьмите вот этот запрос и выполните его на тех данных, что выкладывали. Он даст 3 записи. Для одной из которых есть данные в `punishment`, а для других двух нет. После этого уберите слово LEFT из запроса и посмотрите результат - у вас будет только 1 запись, именно та для которой есть данные во всех таблицах. LEFT собственно и показывает необязательность наличия данных в указанной в нем таблице